# Sequence of numbers as single feature

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, algorithms

Is it possible to use a sequence of numbers as one feature?

For example, using libsvm data format:

```
<label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2>

+1 1:123.02 2:1.23 3:5.45,2.22,6.76
+1 1:120.12 2:2.23 3:4.98,2.55,4.45
-1 1:199.99 2:2.13 3:4.98,2.22,6.98
...
```

Is there any special machine learning algorithm for this kind of data?

Comment: The format and data sample shown is likely the LIBSVM format. The first is the label (+1 or -1), followed by dimension/value pairs. This format is convenient for sparse vector storage. From the example, there might be a problem with format (I see the commas at the end). You can use LIBSVM software package on this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 solutions:

- You aggregate each sequence of numbers into a single number, which use as a feature. There exist plenty of aggregation functions, such as some derived from descriptive statistics root-mean-square, kurtosis, skewness, max, min, duration, standard deviation, crest factor, mean, or more specific aggregation such as fourier transforms or wavelet transforms.
- You use some model that accepts sequences as input. Sequences may be of variable length. Example of such model: [recurrent neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), [Dynamic Bayesian networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Bayesian_network).

Comment: @Franck Your first suggestion works fine with other type of data, but it won't capture the temporal dependence that's what makes a sequential data so unique.

Comment: @horaceT I agree. The first solution relies on the aggregation functions, which is often not great for time series.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Your second point is not quite accurate. RNN could deal with sequences of different length. In fact, that's what makes it work so well as a language model.

Comment: @horaceT Good point, I'm not sure what I had in mind when writing this. Fixed!